# Loading and caching multiple UIImageView in a tableview cell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, haneke

I have a custom table view cell with 3 UIImageView. I load and cache them asynchroneously with [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift). When I scroll back up, some of the previoulsy seen images disappear randomly. This is really strange. Why is this happening ?

I have tried SDWebImage as well but the problem persisted.

In setUserProfileImage, I use [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) to load and cache my images :

```
import Haneke

func setUserProfileImage(image: UIImageView, userImageId:String) {
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/" + userImageId + "/pictures?access_token="+Const.headers["x-access-token"]!)
    image.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
    rectangleImage(image)
}

func rectangleImage(image: UIImageView) {
    image.roundCorners()
    image.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Custom table view cell :

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic3: UIImageView!

    var cellGroup : Group = Group()

    func configureGroup (m: Group) {
        cellGroup = m
    }

    func configureCell() {
        setUsersImage()
    }

    func setUsersImage() {
        setUserProfileImage(profilePic, userImageId: cellGroup.users[0].substringFromIndex(cellGroup.users[0].startIndex.advancedBy(1)))
        if  cellGroup.users.count > 1 {
            setUserProfileImage(profilePic2, userImageId: cellGroup.users[1].substringFromIndex(cellGroup.users[1].startIndex.advancedBy(1)))
            if (cellGroup.users.count > 2) {
                setUserProfileImage(profilePic3, userImageId: cellGroup.users[2].substringFromIndex(cellGroup.users[2].startIndex.advancedBy(1)))
            }
            else {
                profilePic3.hidden = true
            }
        }
        else {
            profilePic2.hidden = true
            profilePic3.hidden = true
        }
    }
    ...
  }
```

My table view controller :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        reloadCellAtIndexPathRow(indexPath.row, cell: cell)
        return cell
}

func reloadCellAtIndexPathRow(groupIndex : Int, cell: MomentTableViewCell) {
        cell.configureGroup(groups[groupIndex])
        cell.configureCell()
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        cell.backgroundColor = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the hidden UIImageView to reappear therefore they seem to be hidden only when reusued.

Change your code to

```
func configureCell() {
    profilePic3.hidden = false
    profilePic2.hidden = false
    setUsersImage()
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that.  I knew it had something to do with the fact that cells are reused. Thanks